# i18next: overwrites nested items

Tags: javascript, jquery, i18next

I'm using `i18next` to translate my form. It works fine but I have problems with nested items, for example:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
     <div class="checkbox">
         <label class="form" data-i18n="form.checkbox">
             <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="true" required>                                        
         </label>
     </div>
</div>
```

After applying the translation, the actual HTML code is like this:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
     <div class="checkbox">
         <label class="form" data-i18n="form.checkbox">
             translated value (no more <input> tag!)
         </label>
     </div>
</div>
```

It overwrites the `innerHTML` with the translation string.
Instead I need to "save" existing items and append the translation after them.

What is the correct use of `i18next` on a checkbox form entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
<div class="checkbox">                                        
    <label class="form">                                            
        <input id="input_flag2" type="checkbox" name="disclaimer2" value="true" required>
        <span data-i18n="form.checkbox"></span>
    </label>                                        
</div>
```

The `span` tag does the trick, embedding the translated content.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

```
$('[data-i18n]').each(function each() {
  const el = $(this);
  const contents = el.contents();

  el.text(i18n.t($(this).attr('data-i18n')))
    .append(contents);
});
```

### Edit:

The above is oversimplifying the problem because, as you pointed out, it won't work for custom attributes.

Therefore I searched a bit more and I found out it's already supported by [jquery-i18next#append-content](https://github.com/i18next/jquery-i18next#append-content) like this:

```
<label class="form" data-i18n="[append]form.checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="true" required>                                        
</label>
```

You can either specify a custom attribute or one of the special attributes like **prepend, append**, etc. to specify where you want the translated text to appear. More info on [jquery i18next doc](https://github.com/i18next/jquery-i18next#set-innerhtml-attributes)

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypacLpok/)

Comment: It doesn't work with custom tags (i.e. `[placeholder]form.blabla`) and when switching to other languages it appends over and over the previous content.

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit anymore my comment. I meant custom *attributes* of course.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I never used the custom attributes before therefore I didn't know they exist. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: With `i18next` 1.8.0 the `[append]` keyword will append over and over the translated text. I'm afraid I have to switch to `jquery-i18next`

Comment: I installed also `jquery-i18next` but I confirm the wrong behavior of the `[append]` keyword. I'm not using it correctly because it should work, of course!